# Why are R and Python Mann Whitney different?

Tags: python, r, statistics

I am wondering why my answers are so different when doing a mann whitney u test in python and in R. In python:

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
t = [1,2,3]
g = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
mannwhitneyu(t,g)
(0.0, 0.014092901073953692)
```

In R:

```
t = c(1,2,3)
g = c(4,5,6,7,8,9)
wilcox.test(t,g, paired = FALSE)

   Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  t and g
W = 0, p-value = 0.02381
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

I'm wondering why the python one looks more like a one sided test.

Comment: See http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100153716/if-the-mann-whitney-u-test-returns-a-one-sided-p-value-what-is-the-null-hypothesis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scipy version is documented to return a one-sided p-value.  (The doc site is down for me at the moment so I can't provide a link, but you can see it if you look at the help for the `mannwhitneyu` function.)  The R function is [documented](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) to allow you to specify the sidedness, with two-sided as the default.

Comment: The scipy[https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html] version can be parameterised to return two-sided value. However, the result I get for U statistics is different in R (Statistics = 200) and Python (statistics = 1400). Any idea why?

Comment: @MrT77: Please ask a separate question providing a minimal code example.

Comment: @MrT77: You just linked back to this same question.

Answer (score 0):

MW Test in scipy is not to be applied for sample sizes less than 20. See note in its documentation. Hence your python results are not accurate.

From the link below

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

"
Notes

Use only when the number of observation in each sample is > 20 and you have 2 independent samples of ranks. Mann-Whitney U is significant if the u-obtained is LESS THAN or equal to the critical value of U.

This test corrects for ties and by default uses a continuity correction.
"

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important and relevant information in the link provided in the answer itself. This can help stop your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.